# How to split string into units of each character

Tags: rust

I want to take a string where there are characters that may be repeated and split the string into units of each character.

So for example

```
aaaabbbabbbaaaacccbbbbbbbbaaa
```

would become

```
[ aaaa, bbb, a, bbb, aaaa, ccc, bbbbbbbb, aaa ]
```

Comment: Could you define what you mean by "character"?

Comment: @BurntSushi5 any char, whether it be a letter, number, punctuation, or what have you.

Comment: @wolfenstien98 Are you familiar with Unicode or UTF-8 at all? The concept of a "character" in programming usually doesn't match with what a human thinks. For example, "Åström" has 6 `char`s, but "Åström" has 8! ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character)) Then there are the *complicated* parts of Unicode.

Answer (score 9):

A succinct way is to use [`Itertools::group_by`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.7/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.group_by) on an iterator of `char`s:

```
extern crate itertools;

use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let input = "aaaabbbabbbaaaacccbbbbbbbbaaa";

    let output: Vec<String> = input
        .chars()
        .group_by(|&x| x)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(_, r)| r.collect())
        .collect();

    assert_eq!(
        output,
        ["aaaa", "bbb", "a", "bbb", "aaaa", "ccc", "bbbbbbbb", "aaa"]
    );
}
```

However, this requires creating new `Strings` for each group of characters. A more efficient solution would return slices to the original string.

A (hacky) modification to the previous solution yields these:

```
let mut start = input;
let output: Vec<&str> = input
    .chars()
    .group_by(|&x| x)
    .into_iter()
    .map(|(_, r)| {
        let len: usize = r.map(|c| c.len_utf8()).sum();
        let (a, b) = start.split_at(len);
        start = b;
        a
    })
    .collect();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you think that an external tool is overkill, you can do this like that:

```
fn group_chars(mut input: &str) -> Vec<&str> {
    fn first_different(mut chars: std::str::Chars) -> Option<usize> {
        chars.next().map(|f| chars.take_while(|&c| c == f).fold(f.len_utf8(), |len, c| len + c.len_utf8()))
    }

    let mut output = Vec::new();

    while let Some(different) = first_different(input.chars()) {
        let (before, after) = input.split_at(different);
        input = after;
        output.push(before);
    }

    output
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(
        group_chars("aaaabbbébbbaaaacccbbbbbbbbaaa"),
        ["aaaa", "bbb", "é", "bbb", "aaaa", "ccc", "bbbbbbbb", "aaa"]
    );
}
```

Or you can do an iterator:

```
pub struct CharGroups<'a> {
    input: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> CharGroups<'a> {
    pub fn new(input: &'a str) -> CharGroups<'a> {
        CharGroups { input }
    }
}

impl<'a> Iterator for CharGroups<'a> {
    type Item = &'a str;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<&'a str> {
        self.input.chars().next().map(|f| {
            let i = self.input.find(|c| c != f).unwrap_or(self.input.len());
            let (before, after) = self.input.split_at(i);
            self.input = after;
            before
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(
        CharGroups::new("aaaabbbébbbaaaacccbbbbbbbbaaa").collect::<Vec<_>>(),
        ["aaaa", "bbb", "é", "bbb", "aaaa", "ccc", "bbbbbbbb", "aaa"]
    );
}
```